# styling error when added styles using ngClass

Tags: css, angularjs, typescript

When I only use class name like error and info the css works

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-i4uqtt-zrz3jb (using Angular latest version)

but when I renamed the css class and add more styles like for the example below the css and [ngClass] no longer work. Any idea guys ?
#HTML

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
  <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 7%">
    <mat-icon 
    [ngClass]="password.hasError('mininum') ? 'error-check-outline' : 'info-check-outline'">
    check_circle_outline </mat-icon>
  </div>
  <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 100%">
    <span 
    [ngClass]="password.hasError('mininum') ? 'text-info-error' : 'text-info'">
    8 characters mininum</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

#ts

```
validateMinimumPassword: ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl) => {
  if (control.value.length < 8) {
    return { minimum: true };
  }
  return null;
};
```

#CSS

```
.text-info {
  font-family: Inter;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #4caf50;
  font-family: Manrope;
  margin-top: 2.5px;
}

.text-info-error {
  font-family: Inter;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #DDD;
  font-family: Manrope;
  margin-top: 2.5px;
}

.error-check-outline {
  transform: scale(.74);
  color: #DDD;
}

.info-check-outline {
  transform: scale(.74);
  color: #4caf50;
}
```

Comment: you have to use `ngClass` with `{}`

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: can you please post an answer Sir based on the code above so I can vote your answer , thanks.

Comment: your syntax is wrong. check [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description) ... it should be like `[ngClass]="{...}"`

Comment: you mean [ngClass]="{password.hasError('mininum') ? 'error-check-outline' : 'info-check-outline'}" ?  that would be error

Comment: you have to change the syntax see my answer

Comment: The syntax is not wrong. Ternary operator works well with `ngClass`. Example: `<div [ngClass]="varA === varB ? 'css-class-1' : 'css-class-2'">`

Comment: can you please post an answer Sir based on my example  thank you

Comment: @naveen  but I am not comparing if === I am checking if hasError

Comment: but the css are not taking effect

Comment: Modified code and working fine in given demo.

Comment: @RajivPatelKumar: ternary operator LHS evaluates to `bool`. It doesn't matter whether you are comparing or calling a function. *Added answer*

Comment: Hi Sir @DevangPatel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191741/password-match-angularjs-validation ..maybe  you have idea with this problem Sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything should work, if you correct your typo <strike>mininum</strike>. Its **minimum**.

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-68358839

---

#### Update: Why its green

You have the expression `"password.hasError('mininum') ? 'text-info-error' : 'text-info'"`

The [ternary(conditional) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) syntax is like,

> condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse

You gave `password.hasError('mininum')` and as it has a typo it returns null, which is `falsey`. So now the expression on the left is false,
and the `.text-info` will get selected. As *that* style makes the color green, it will become green.

Comment: Hi Sir , on my code now when the page loads why is that the text is already green I followed the code on stackblitz , what seem to be the issue ,

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your `ngClass` condition in `{}` also change syntax

For Example:

```
[ngClass]="{'error-check-outline': password.hasError('minimum'), 'info-check-outline' : !password.hasError('minimum'
)}"
```

Comment: I follow this one Sir but the css is still does not take effect

Comment: please check f12 to see if class apply on DOM also look in F12 what happened to your css

Answer (score 0):

you can write a method to return class based on condition

```
setClass(type) {
  if (type == 'minimum') {
    return 'class-one';
  } else if (type == 'maxmimum') {
    return 'class-two';
  }
}
```

and then use this method in HTML like below

```
<div [ngClass]="setClass('minimum')"><div>
```

using this way you can clean your HTML